# how to retain only certain rows/columns that meet the threshold in python

Tags: python, r

so I want to retain only certain rows/columns that meet the threshold.
actually I have code in R that retain only these rows and columns that meet the threshold:

```
repeat {                                       # Repeat whatever is in the brackets
  i <- sum(dim(M))                             # Check the size of M
  M <- M[rowSums(M) >= 50, colSums(M) >= 150]  # Retain only these rows/columns that meet the threshold
  if (sum(dim(M)) == i) break                  # If the size has not changed, break the loop
  }
```

Just not sure how to convert that into python.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what `M` is? And can you clarify what the expected behavior is and/or what you've done to try to recreate it in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R:

```
M = matrix(c(70,10,20,90,30,15,80,50,40,20,50,5),ncol=3)                           
i = dim(M)
M <- M[rowSums(M) >= 50, colSums(M) >= 150]
M
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   70   30
[2,]   20   80
[3,]   90   50

dim(M)
[1] 3 2

i
[1] 4 3

identical(i,dim(M))
[1] FALSE
```

In python, it's easier to have the matrix as a np array, and then use the `.sum()` method with `axis = 1` for row and `axis = 0` for columns, to create the boolean for subsetting the matrix :

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[70,30,40],[10,15,20],[20,80,50],[90,50,5]])
i = M.shape

M = M[M.sum(axis=1)>=50][:,M.sum(axis=0)>=150]
array([[70, 30],
       [20, 80],
       [90, 50]])

M.shape == i
Out[25]: False
```